# Linq: select parent based on sub collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a type "Download" has a collection of "IEnumerable" and are trying to return a collection of downloads where a product in the collection matches condition.
This below is my attempt thus far. I think the problem is I need to select the parent, as I receive cast errors subtypeA wont cast to parent etc.

```
    public static IEnumerable<Download> GetDownloadsBasedOnProductId(int prodid)
    {
        var downloads =
            (IEnumerable<Download>)
            MyDataContext.Instance.Downloads.SelectMany(
                    x => x.bmdAType).Where(
                                     a => a.Id == prodid);
        return downloads;
    }
```

Any ideas on how to return the correct type when querying a collection of subitems?

Comment: Can you add the declarations of the Download and Product class? Without, this question can be answered only by guessing.

Comment: Thanks for response. bmdAType is a IEnumerable<Product> - is there more info needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
public static IEnumerable<Download> GetDownloadsBasedOnProductId(int prodid)
{
    return MyDataContext.Instance
                        .Downloads
                        .Where(download => downloads.Any(a => a.Id == prodid));
}
```

Comment: Possibly, it does throw an error "object reference not set" when attempting to execute, but the logic seems sound. I'll look into it more